# Application wide SpiceManager in Android using RoboSpice

Tags: android, caching, robospice

I've implemented a `BitmapSpiceManager` and `BitmapRequest` in my app to download an image or fetch from the cache if already downloaded. The problem is following the examples given by RoboSpice, the caching only works within one `Activity`. If you end that activity (by going back to a previous one for example) and then launch it again, the cache does not contain what was loaded in it before (it's cleared).

I'm following the pattern where you have a base activity that holds a `BitmapSpiceManager` and from my subclass activity I make a request using the manager. This gets the file and caches it, I proved it comes from the cache again within the activity by hooking up a button which removes the ImageView then trys to load the image again.

Is it possible to have the images cached in one Activity available in another? I need like an application wide SpiceManager. Ideally the cached items could persist beyond application runs too i.e. cache for a few hours. Is there a better way to structure the RoboSpice code in applications than the examples?

If I subclass `BitmapSpiceService` and override the `createCacheManager()` method is that going to help? I could use `DiskLruCache` but the `BitmapSpiceService` uses `InFileBitmapObjectPersister` which says it writes files out, so I figure it's the same. I'm not sure why the cache is cleared when the Activity dies.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing in the first few paragraphs is exactly how RoboSpice works.  No matter how many `SpiceManager`s you have throughout your application, they will all bind to the same `SpiceService` declared in your manifest.  As long as you call SpiceManager.execute before the cacheExpiryDuration expires and use the same requestCacheKey, the data will be returned from the cache instead of the network.

Can you post the code you're using to make the request?